# Make a resultant array with comparing two arrays

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays like

```
let arr1 = [
  {id:1, name:'hhj'},
  {id:12, name:'ghdgj'},
  {id:5, name:'gd'}
  ]

let arr2 = [
{id:1, addr:'fsfhg'},
{id:8,addr:'rgdh},
{id:5, name:'gd'}
]
```

I want a resultant array by comparing two arrays id like,

```
resultarr =[{id:1, name:'hhj'}
   {id:5, name:'gd'}]

let names=[hhj,gd]
```

I want this names in seperate array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Not much. It only returns boolean

Comment: Ok but the essence remains the same. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript) is more focused with your use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to obtain the objects whose id is in both arrays, you could do this:

```js
let result = array1.filter(el1 => array2.some(el2 => o1.id === el2.id));
```

Comment: I udated my  question.Can you please check it?

Comment: You can use the Array.map function to return only the names of the elements of the resulting list like ```let names = array.map(elem => elem.name)```

Answer (score 0):

your expected result is incorrect`resultarr =[{{id:1, name:'hhj'}}]`

in the first object you must set property like

```
resultarr =[{foo: {id:1, name:'hhj'}}]
```